# How to check if a cron job is running or not?

Tags: php, cron

I added the following command in `crontab -e`:

```
15 * * * * php /home/rizwan/PHP-workspace/mgstore/testcron.php
```

I need to run `testcron.php` every 15 minutes; for testing purposes I used the following PHP code in `testcron.php`:

```php
<?php 
echo "test";
```

Comment: Do you want to check if the job is running from the shell? Or do you want to check if the process is running from a PHP script?

Comment: And where is that "echo" supposed to end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
15 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/rizwan/PHP-workspace/mgstore/testcron.php >> /home/rizwan/cron.out
```

this was working .but i have one php script,for adding customers from magento to ERP,when i run script manually,it asks for authorization,after accepting it creates customers into ERP from magento,I need whenever i added customer in magento after 5 or 10 mins this script should run and add the customer to ERP.how this can be done ?,If any one have any idea,please help ?

Comment: we can  do it by using event Observer method

Comment: Why did you post an answer and accepted it if this does not solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to be sure to run the executable by complete path. you can get the path using `which` command

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```

Now the entry in crontab must be:

```
15 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/rizwan/PHP-workspace/mgstore/testcron.php
```

Now To check the output you can use redirection trick, so redirect the output to some file and then you can check the file to see the result. So the entry would be:

```
15 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/rizwan/PHP-workspace/mgstore/testcron.php >> /home/rizwan/cron.out
```

Now you can check the file in your home named `cron.out` and see if your cron run or not.

Comment: @Rizwan you are welcome friend

Comment: 15 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/rizwan/PHP-workspace/mgstore/testcron.php >> /home/rizwan/cron.out   

            this was working .but i have one php script,for adding customers from magento to ERP,when i run script manually,it asks for authorization,after accepting it creates customers into ERP from magento,I need whenever i added customer in magento after 5 or 10 mins this script should run and add the customer to ERP.how this can be done ?,If any one have any idea,please help ?

Comment: @Rizwan It's better to make it as new answer to get help more than a comment here

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you you can use either the backtick operator or the `shell_exec()` function to run a command in the system's default shell; you could run `pgrep 'php /home/rizwan/PHP-workspace/mgstore/testcron.php'` and evaluate its return code; either this:

```php
<?php
    if(!($PID = `pgrep 'php /home/rizwan/PHP-workspace/mgstore/testcron.php'`))
        echo 'Process is running with PID ' . $PID . '.';
?>
```

Or this:

```php
<?php
    if(!($PID = shell_exec("pgrep 'php /home/rizwan/PHP-workspace/mgstore/testcron.php'")))
        echo 'Process is running with PID ' . $PID . '.';
?>
```