# How to check if a cron job is running or not through php script?

Tags: php, cron, magento

Back to my question [How to check if a cron job is running or not?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650885/how-to-check-if-a-cron-job-is-running-or-not/650891?noredirect=1#comment936198_650891), the answer there is valid which stated to redirect output to a file and test.

```
15 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/rizwan/PHP-workspace/mgstore/testcron.php >> /home/rizwan/cron.out
```

Anyway this was working , but i have one php script,for adding customers from magento to ERP,when i run script manually,it asks for authorization,after accepting it creates customers into ERP from magento,I need whenever i added customer in magento after 5 or 10 mins this script should run and add the customer to ERP.how this can be done ?,If any one have any idea,please help ?

Comment: This can be done provided you know the way to check whether you have added a new customer in magento..